# как называются такие элементы дизайна?

Tags: svg, веб-дизайн

как называются такие элементы дизайна и где их можно посмотреть большой выбор , на подобии этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На такой вопрос, Google выдал 34,100,000 результатов ))) Уточните, что вы хотите, а то вопрос закроют.

Comment: Посмотреть можно в Adobe Illustrator или Inkscape, они там успешно делаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, это называется виньетка.
А поискать можно по запросу "vignette", или "vignette line".